# Phusion Passenger set default oom_adj

Tags: apache, passenger

I work for a company that runs a ruby app that depends on httpd+passenger.

- OS: Centos 7.4
- Passenger Version: 5.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
- Httpd Version: 2.4.6-67.el7

I've noticed that if there is a memory leak in the ruby application the Linux OOM manger will never kill the passenger process that uses all the memory because the Passenger Core process changes it's oom_adj value to -17 (which disables ) from killing processes forked from it.

I've confirmed that httpd runs with an `oom_adj == 0`, but Passenger Core which gets forked from httpd runs with an `oom_adj == -17`. I've read the configuration docs several times now for passenger and cannot find a config option that allows me to change the value back to 0.

Is Passenger core running with an oom_adj of -17 intentional, or have I discovered a bug?

Also is there a way to configure Phusion Passenger to run with a desired oom_adj value?

```html
sudo systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-04-24 21:37:12 UTC; 26s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 31269 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31280 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 4; Current requests/sec: 0.3; Current traffic: 1.2KB/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─31280 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─31307 Passenger watchdog
           ├─31310 Passenger core
           ├─31330 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─31331 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─31332 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─31333 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─31334 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─31345 Passenger AppPreloader: /srv/websites/{{ domain }}/current
           ├─31415 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─31434 Passenger RubyApp: /srv/websites/{{ domain }}/current (production)
           ├─31444 Passenger RubyApp: /srv/websites/{{ domain }}/current (production)
           ├─31458 Passenger RubyApp: /srv/websites/{{ domain }}/current (production)
           └─31515 Passenger RubyApp: /srv/websites/{{ domain }}/current (production)
           
cat /proc/31280/oom_adj 
0
cat /proc/31310/oom_adj 
-17
cat /proc/31434/oom_adj 
-17
```